# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.samplemap.CustomItemizedOverlay

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am working on using mapviewballons in my Android google-map project but I seem to be having a problem with the above.

```
09-08 02:15:11.792: E/AndroidRuntime(484): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-08 02:15:11.792: E/AndroidRuntime(484): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.samplemap.CustomItemizedOverlay
```

I have combed through the code and am yet to find exactly where this problem is coming from. Would appreciate any help you can afford to help me solve this problem please.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        final MapController mc = mapView.getController(); 
        mc.setZoom(16);

        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
       // Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker);
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
        CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem> itemizedoverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem>(drawable, mapView);

        LocalGeoPoints loc = new LocalGeoPoints();
        for (CustomOverlayItem a : loc.overlayitems) {
            itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(a);
        } 
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);


    }



public class CustomItemizedOverlay<Item extends OverlayItem> extends BalloonItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem> {

    private ArrayList<CustomOverlayItem> m_overlays = new ArrayList<CustomOverlayItem>();
    private Context c = null;

    public CustomItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, MapView mapView) {

        super(boundCenter(defaultMarker), mapView);
        c = mapView.getContext();
    }

    public void addOverlay(CustomOverlayItem overlay) {
        m_overlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected CustomOverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return m_overlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return m_overlays.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onBalloonTap(int index, CustomOverlayItem item) {
        Toast.makeText(c, "onBalloonTap for overlay index " + index,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected BalloonOverlayView<CustomOverlayItem> createBalloonOverlayView() {
        // use our custom balloon view with our custom overlay item type:
        return new CustomBalloonOverlayView<CustomOverlayItem>(getMapView().getContext(), getBalloonBottomOffset());
    }

}
```

Comment: check your .classpath file if you are using eclipse

Comment: I made the change to classpath as suggested here http://dotnetmackenzie.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/android-could-not-find-helloworldapk.html

Comment: Ummm... It may be possible that there are 2 or more classes having same name `CustomItemizedOverlay` , one is in your package, second may be in any `jar` you are using..so check for that..and remove the extra one..

Comment: How do I check for this? Any easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

please  make public class CustomItemizedOverlay to private class